# In XSLT how to open document, with %20 in its name itself?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have to process one Xml which is having %20 in its name from Xslt.
Filename: Sample%20Documnet.XML

In Xslt i have written like this,

```
<xsl:variable name="readDoc" select="document('Sample%20Documnet.XML')"/>
```

But i am getting this error: Could not find file 'C:\xslt\Sample Documnet.XML'.

I think %20 is getting converted to space internally, which i don't want. Is there any way to stop this behavior.

Comment: Why can't you just open `Sample%20Documnet.XML` without any special handling of the %20?

Comment: You need to escape once more: `Sample%2520Documnet.XML`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Dan , it's working  :)